# batch add users to nextcloud on docker with csv

Tags: csv, posix, sh, docker

I have a working script that will batch add users to an instance of nextcloud running on top of docker. This version is the result of changes made after asking this [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/216335/batch-upload-users-to-nextcloud-on-docker-with-bash-csv/216345?noredirect=1#comment418813_216345).

I guess I'm looking for a re-review to ensure that I haven't missed anything. I'm also interested if there are areas where I could make things better in terms of readability, performance, security, etc. You're the reviewer. My code is your oyster.

```
#!/bin/sh

set -eu

# Handle printing errors
die () {
  printf '%s\n' "$1" >&2
  exit 1
}

message () {
  printf '%s\n' "$1" >&2
}

usage () {
  cat <<'EOF'
NAME
      batch_up - batch upload users

SYNOPSIS
      batch_up -?
      batch_up -h
      batch_up --help
      batch_up -v
      batch_up -vv
      batch_up -vvv
      batch_up --verbose
      batch_up -d
      batch_up --delimiter
      batch_up --delimiter=

DESCRIPTION
      Batch_up is a program that adds a batch of users to an instance of NextCloud
      running inside of a docker container by reading a comma separated list from 
      stdin or a csv file. Stdin is the default and will be used if no file is 
      supplied. The delimiter does not have to be a comma, and can be set via the
      -d flag.

      CSV file should be formatted in one of the following configurations:
      username,Display Name,group,email@address.domain
      username,Display Name,group
      username,Display Name
      username

      CSV files should not include the header.

OPTIONS
      -? or -h or --help
            This option displays a summary of the commands accepted by batch_up.

      -v or -vv or -vvv or --verbose
            This option sets the verbosity. Each v adds to the verbosity.
            See the occ command for OwnCloud/NextCloud for more details as this
            option is passed on to the occ command.

            If this option is not passed, the default behavior is to pass the
            -q option to occ (the quiet option), making occ non-verbose.

      -d or --delimiter or --delimiter=
            This option allows you to choose which delimiter you would like to use.
            The following are acceptable characters for this option. ,.;:|

ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES
      OC_PASS
            Sets the password for users added. The OC_PASS environment variable
            is required.

EXAMPLES
      The command:
            batch_up.sh foobar.csv
            Will add the users from foobar.csv. Users will be given the password
            in the OC_PASS environment variable. 

      The command:
            batch_up.sh <<< "jack,Jack Frost,users,jack.frost@gmail.com"
            Will add the user jack, set his display name to Jack Frost, add him
            to the group users, and set his email to jack.frost@gmail.com.

      The command:
            echo "jack,Jack Frost,users,jack.frost@gmail.com" | batch_up.sh
            Will add the user jack, set his display name to Jack Frost, add him
            to the group users, and set his email to jack.frost@gmail.com.

      The command:
             batch_up.sh -d : foobar.csv
            Will set the delimiter to : and add the users from foobar.csv.

EOF
}


# Set verbosity. Default is silent.
verbose=-q

# flags
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
  case $1 in
    -h|-\?|--help)
      usage # Display a usage synopsis.
      exit
      ;;
    -v|-vv|-vvv|--verbose)
      verbose=$1
      ;;
    -d|--delimiter)
      if [ $# -gt 1 ]
      then
        case $2 in
          ,|.|\;|:|\|)
            delimiter=$2
            shift
            ;;
          *)
            die 'Error: delimiter should be one of ,.;:| characters.'
        esac 
      else
        die 'Error: "--delimiter requires a non-empty option argument.'
      fi
      ;;
    --delimiter=?*)
      case ${1#*=} in # Delete everything up to the = and assign the remainder.
        ,|.|\;|:|\|)
          delimiter=${1#*=}
          shift
          ;;
        *)
          die 'Error: delimiter should be one of ,.;:| characters.'
      esac 
      ;;
    --delimiter=) # Handle the case of empty --delimiter=
      die 'Error: "--delimiter=" requires a non-empty option argument.'
      ;;
    --)
      shift
      break
      ;;
    -?*)
      printf 'WARN: Unknown option (ignored): %s\n' "$1" >&2
      ;;
    *) # Default case. No more options, so break out of the loop
      break
  esac

  shift
done

# Is the file readable?
if [ $# -gt 0 ] 
then
  [ -r "$1" ] || die "$1: Couldn't read file."
fi

# Is the OC_PASS environment variable set?
[ ${OC_PASS:-} ] || die "$0: No password specified. Run with --help for more info."

status=true                     # until a command fails

message 'Adding users'

while IFS=${delimiter:-,} read -r f1 f2 f3 f4
do
  if [ "$f1" ]
  then
    docker-compose exec -T -e OC_PASS --user www-data app php occ \
      user:add --password-from-env \
      ${verbose:+"$verbose"} \
      ${f2:+"--display-name=$f2"} \
      ${f3:+"--group=$f3"} \
      "$f1" </dev/null \
      || status=false

    # If there is a fourth value in the csv, use it to set the user email.
    if [ "$f4" ]
    then
      docker-compose exec -T \
        --user www-data app php occ \
        user:setting "$f1" settings email "$f4" \
        </dev/null \
        || status=false
    fi
  else
    echo "Expected at least one field, but none were supplied." >&2
    status=false
    continue
  fi
message '...'
done <"${1:-/dev/stdin}"

message 'Done'

exec $status
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Don't repeat yourself

There is redundant logic in the processing of the `-d` and `--delimiter=...` options. I would eliminate that, to be something more like this:

```
-d|--delimiter)
  [ $# -gt 1 ] && arg=$1 || arg=
  parseDelimiter "$arg"
  ;;
--delimiter=*)
  parseDelimiter "${1#*=}"
  ;;
```

Where `parseDelimiter` is a function that will parse the passed argument and set `delimiter` appropriately, or exit with an error.

#### A simpler pattern in `case` (maybe)

Instead of `,|.|\;|:|\|)`, perhaps `[,.\;:\|])` is slightly simpler and easier to type (less likely you mistype something, for example less likely to forget a `|` between the different allowed values).

#### Assign positional arguments to descriptive variables early on

Near the end of the script I see `done <"${1:-/dev/stdin}"`, and wonder:
*what was `$1` again?*
I think it's easier to understand when positional arguments are assigned to variables with descriptive names early on in a script.

#### Prefer comments on their own lines

I read code from top to bottom,
and this line makes my eyes make an unnecessary detour to the right:

> ```
> status=true                     # until a command fails
> ```

I would have preferred that comment on its own line just before the code it's referring to.

Incidentally, I don't understand what this comment is trying to say.
The `status` variable is used to determine the exit status of the program.
In this script, it will be "failure" if some failure happened in the loop body, otherwise "success".

I would have named this `exit_status`, and then at the end of the script do `exit "$exit_status"`, rather than the current `exec $status`, which I find a bit odd.